# return to home screen on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

How do I return to Android's home screen on the emulator from anywhere? The home key does not seem to work. I am using Android 2.1.

**EDIT:** It is working when I use the sdk but when I compile from the AOSP sources (version 2.1) it does not work. Perhaps someone encountered this problem.

Comment: same problem here. Using the intel x86 image, the home button doesn't work.

Answer (score 14):

Use the Escape key.

(Why the answer should be bigger than 30 chars?)

Comment: No, this does not work. The Esc key is bound to the BACK key and the BACK key can be programmed to not return to the previous screen. Actually the Home key (both the device key and the key on the physical keyboard) will work but somehow this is not working.

Comment: thank you very much for giving suggestion of Escape key. But still I'm wondering why the home and back keys are not working

Answer (score 5):

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#KeyMapping

Brevity is good but  teaching the chap to fish is better

Comment: Not when the link 404's...